# npm error in Laravel 7 when running npm run dev

Tags: npm, laravel-7

I use Windows 10. I just installed Laravel 7 and I created a new project using the following command:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel briscola
```

Then I added the following code in app.scss file to render a red background:

```
body {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Then I run the following code to use the current app.scss file:

```
npm run dev
```

However unfortunately the previous command didn't work and I saw the following error:

```
> @ dev C:\xampp\htdocs\briscola
> npm run development

npm WARN invalid config loglevel="notice"

> @ development C:\xampp\htdocs\briscola
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

"cross-env" non è riconosciuto come comando interno o esterno,
 un programma eseguibile o un file batch.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Della Mea Michele\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-05T15_14_25_432Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Della Mea Michele\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-05T15_14_26_197Z-debug.log
```

Have you any idea about this error and how to solve it?

Comment: I have updated my answer, can you try again?

Comment: @andy I tried but when I run rm package-lock.json yarn.lock I received rm: cannot remove 'yarn.lock': No such file or directory. Then when I run npm install cross-env I received many warnings.. is it possible that my current version of node (6.11.2) is too old? Finally when I run npm run dev I receive errors after that row: at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\briscola\node_modules\cross-env\src\bin\cross-env.js:3:18)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

actually try this,

```sh
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
```

Then

```sh
npm install cross-env

npm install
```

Finally

```sh
npm run dev
```

Comment: I solved... simply I updated node from 6.11.2 to 12.16.1 and then I followed your steps. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To run `npm run dev` You should run this command first:

```
npm install
```

If any error appears then you should install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) first.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I used that command npm install but nothing changed... it appears always the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I did all the accepted answers in this thread (and other threads too) but to no avail. What really solved my problem regarding this issue was:

1. Uninstall my node.js
2. Manually delete all npm and node_modules folder in my C:\Program Files (or wherever you might have installed it because '**uninstalling**' sometimes won't delete data folders)
3. Made sure I removed the file path C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Roaming\npm on my Environment Variables
4. Downloaded this node version for my Windows 7 [LINK HERE](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v13.6.0/) then installed it freshly. Important: Don't forget to restart your computer after the installation!

These steps were successful and you can try it if above answers don't work.

Now when I rechecked my versions, they are now fine and working and won't give errors.

```
$ npm -v
6.13.4

$ node -v
v13.6.0

$ npx -v
6.13.4
```